# Change domain on exchange server login credentials

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am trying to setup Outlook 2010 in Windows 7 Pro to connect to my company's exchange server.  However, when I try to enter my username and password to verify my account, it forces me to use a default domain of clayton-pc (my computer name).  I need to use a domain of CORP.  How do I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either "DOMAIN\USERNAME" or "USERNAME@DOMAIN".

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with the same circumstances (office 2010 on win 7) and it seemed that I needed to change the proxy authentication settings to basic which allowed me to modify the login domain.